# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() NLP pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, pipeline

Hi I am running a NLP pipeline where I am trying to fit a model but I am getting an error. Please check these LoC and suggest what am I doing wrong.

I have tried resampling the scraping and run it with 255 characters and it seems to produce results for it. But when I am trying to run it with 15000 characters(actual length of scraping) I get this error :

> The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

```
    from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
    alltext = pd.concat([training_set.scrape_text, test_set.scrape_text]) 
    alltext.shape 
    rows = [] 
    for row in alltext.values: 
        rows.append(word_tokenize(row)) 
        model = gensim.models.FastText(rows, size=100, window=4, min_count=2, iter=10)
    pipeline = Pipeline([
      ('feats', FeatureUnion([ ("word2vec vectorizer",TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer(model)), 
      ('vec', TfidfVectorizer(preprocessor=preprocessor, tokenizer=word_tokenize,analyzer='word', lowercase=True, strip_accents='unicode', stop_words='english', ngram_range=(1,2)))])),
      ('voting', VotingClassifier(estimators=[("xgb",XGBClassifier(nthread= 4, learning_rate=0.08, n_estimators=1000, max_depth=10))], voting='soft' ))])


#Loggin time for model fitting
start_time = time.time()
pipeline.fit(training_set.scrape_text.values, y)

print("Time taken for modelling with current pipeline --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: add the code for how you created the pipeline, otherwise its hard to understand how does the error occurs!

Comment: How have you built your pipeline? This code is not sufficient to understand how the error occurs.

Comment: I had used FastText for extracting the features and if ```("word2vec vectorizer", TfidfEmbeddingVectorizer(model))``` is commented it is working fine. but i can not understand why not working with this line in the code

Comment: please, don't write your code in the comments, instead you should edit your post

Comment: moreover, could you post the entire stack trace of the error?

Comment: thanks for the recommendation about the edit. I have edited the original post and added the entire code.